# AWS Lambda HTTP/API request using Node.JS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm new to skill dev and am trying to make an API call from within an intent (for the sake of this example, I am just using Google). For whatever reason, the log statements never execute in my HTTP request:

```
var test = http.get('http://www.google.com', function (result) {
  console.log('Success, with: ' + result.statusCode);
}).on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('Error, with: ' + err.message);
});

console.log('test is', test);
```

The test log statement after the request returns a ClientRequest object. Below is the full log output:

```
START RequestId: aaa9d350-3c3c-11e7-8840-4bab41953f86 Version: $LATEST
2017-05-19T02:41:32.961Z    aaa9d350-3c3c-11e7-8840-4bab41953f86    Warning: Application ID is not set
2017-05-19T02:41:33.139Z    aaa9d350-3c3c-11e7-8840-4bab41953f86    test is ClientRequest {
  domain: null,
  _events: 
   { response: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     socket: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onSocket] },
     error: [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 3,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: [ 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: www.google.com\r
Connection: close\r
\r
' ],
  outputEncodings: [ 'latin1' ],
  outputCallbacks: [ [Function: finish] ],
  outputSize: 59,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  upgrading: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedHeader: {},
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: null,
  connection: null,
  _header: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r
Host: www.google.com\r
Connection: close\r
\r
',
  _headers: { host: 'www.google.com' },
  _headerNames: { host: 'Host' },
  _onPendingData: null,
  agent: 
   Agent {
     domain: null,
     _events: { free: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     defaultPort: 80,
     protocol: 'http:',
     options: { path: null },
     requests: {},
     sockets: { 'www.google.com:80:': [Object] },
     freeSockets: {},
     keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
     keepAlive: false,
     maxSockets: Infinity,
     maxFreeSockets: 256 },
  socketPath: undefined,
  timeout: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  _ended: false }
END RequestId: aaa9d350-3c3c-11e7-8840-4bab41953f86
REPORT RequestId: aaa9d350-3c3c-11e7-8840-4bab41953f86  Duration: 338.91 ms Billed Duration: 400 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 46 MB
```

I thought it must be related to it being an async function, but I haven't had any luck.

Is it possibly a setting in AWS Lambda that I need to configure?

Comment: When you test the function from the lambda console, what output do you see? Can you add the output to the question?

Comment: @Yeshodhan Kulkarni I added the full output to my question.

Comment: It sounds like the HTTP request is timing out, which commonly happens when people place a Lambda function inside a VPC that doesn't have a NAT Gateway. Alternatively, you may be explicitly exiting the Lambda function before the `http.get` call has completed, but you would need to show your entire Lambda function's code to determine that.

Comment: @MarkB I've discovered that my alexa.execute(); function is what causes it not to execute, even though I run this after the request happens.

Comment: Please show more of your code. I don't think you are actually running it after the request, due to the way asynchronous calls work in NodeJS. Just because the line of code comes later in your file doesn't mean it runs later. You probably need to move that line into the request callback.